# Create image from 2D Color Array

Tags: java, image, colors, bufferedimage

I have an array called image[][] and i want to create a BufferedImage out of this so I can have the player store it in a file.

Comment: See [`BufferedImage.setRGB(x,y,rgb)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#setRGB%28int,%20int,%20int%29) note it will be slower than some other methods of creating an image from an array.  If that does not answer the question (what is the question, BTW?) post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of your best attempt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
// Initialize Color[][] however you were already doing so.
Color[][] image;

// Initialize BufferedImage, assuming Color[][] is already properly populated.
BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(image.length, image[0].length,
        BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

// Set each pixel of the BufferedImage to the color from the Color[][].
for (int x = 0; x < image.length; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < image[x].length; y++) {
        bufferedImage.setRGB(x, y, image[x][y].getRGB());
    }
}
```

This is a straightforward way of creating (and potentially storing) an image, if that's what you're trying to get at.  However, this is not efficient by any means.  Try it with a larger image and you'll see a noticeable speed difference.

Comment: +1 from before the first edit, but especially for *"this is not efficient by any means"*.  It might also be profitable to examine how the `Color` array is created in the first place, as it might be much quicker to dispense with the array entirely and draw directly to the image.  But that all depends on information that is not known to anyone but the OP.. :(

Comment: Question, what is the difference between BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB and BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB. I recall using ARGB before, but not RBG. Is the A related with alpha?

Comment: @javawarrior I mean... that won't tell us much.  But from that, you can tell that this will run `400 * 400 = 160,000` iterations in this loop.  If `bufferedImage.setRGB(...)` is a slow operation, this conversion could be extremely expensive.

Comment: @Bucco Yes, the A stands for alpha.